# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

so i got this error

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'

any suggestions,

**Models.py**

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)


    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password= bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password, 10)




    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True


    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return (self.id)


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

**Views.py**

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('register.html')
    user = User(request.form['username'] , request.form['password'] )
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    storeduser = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if storeduser.username is not None and storeduser.username == request.form['username']:
        return 'User already Exist !'
    else:
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('User successfully registered')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Pretty much if client username matches a current username output
Existing user registered, if not register username.

im referring to my username in my models(in case you were wondering)

Comment: The `User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()` query returned `None`, meaning the user was not found.

Comment: i kinda dont understand, because the code was able to render 

user already existed when i put in the same username,

how i do make it add a usename and redirect to the index page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()` query returned `None`, meaning the user was not found.

You need to test if `storeduser` is not `None` first, *not* `storeduser.username`:

```
if storeduser is not None and storeduser.username == request.form['username']:
    return 'User already Exist !'
```

Because you queried on `request.form['username']` the latter test is redundant, you only really need to use;

```
if storeduser is not None:
    return 'User already Exist !'
```

Comment: let me give this a go martijn

Comment: how i do i specify if

storeduser == request.form['username']

to make sure the user can sign up with a different username and not  a registered user?

you know what i mean ?

Comment: @EliHood: you don't need to. If `storeduser` is not `None`, you got a result from the database, and that can *only* happen if that user has the same `username` value given in the form. So `if storeduser is not None` is *enough* here.

Comment: in a nutshell can you elaborate when to use none vs using == ?

Comment: @EliHood: see [Python None comparison: should I use "is" or ==?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14247373)

Answer (score -1):

if you are getting an error for serializer put a condition for user is none and raise if user == None:

```
        raise serializers.ValidationError("user is not valid")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).